# Get the number of digits from a number

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm looking for a function $f$ that would give me the following results :

For any $x$ such as  $ x \in \mathbb {N^*}, x>0 $

$f(x) = 1 $ when  $1\leq x < 10$

$f(x) = 2 $ when  $10\leq x < 100$

$f(x) = 3 $ when  $100\leq x < 1000$

and so on ...

So far , I have tried the floor function with no success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[$$\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)

Comment: Just clever. Thanks ;)

Comment: Note this is fundamental to computing. To store the number 4294967295, you need $\lfloor\log_{2}(4294967295)\rfloor + 1 = 32$ bits.